# How to use State Accessors to get properties in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, accessor

One of the functionalities of my bot is handling a Shopping Cart. The user can add items anywhere in the conversation and then finish shopping to close the product cart.

To avoid passing the cart from dialog to dialog I would like to create a `UserProfile` property in the `UserState` (The `UserProfile` property has a `ShoppingCart` attribute) but I don't quite know how to use this properly.

My Main Dialog contains a set of Child Dialogs and some of them need to be able to access the `ShoppingCart` object. I found some examples in the samples but none of them do what I want to achieve. In the State Management sample:

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Get the state properties from the turn context.

            var conversationStateAccessors =  _conversationState.CreateProperty<ConversationData>(nameof(ConversationData));
            var conversationData = await conversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ConversationData());

            var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
            var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userProfile.Name))
            {
                // First time around this is set to false, so we will prompt user for name.
                if (conversationData.PromptedUserForName)
                {   
                    // Set the name to what the user provided.
                    userProfile.Name = turnContext.Activity.Text?.Trim();

                    // Acknowledge that we got their name.
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Thanks {userProfile.Name}. To see conversation data, type anything.");

                    // Reset the flag to allow the bot to go though the cycle again.
                    conversationData.PromptedUserForName = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Prompt the user for their name.
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"What is your name?");

                    // Set the flag to true, so we don't prompt in the next turn.
                    conversationData.PromptedUserForName = true;
                }
            }
```

If I understand correctly, every time he wants to get the accessor a new Property is created? Or once a property is created if you call `CreateProperty` no property will be creater and the accessor is returned?

I thought about getting the accessor on the Bot and then passing it to `MainDialog`and then to the `ChildDialogs` but it kinda defeats the purpose of not passing the `ShoppingCart`through Dialogs.

Can't I get the accessors without having to create a Property every time?

I've read [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1705) which gives a solution to my problem, but then I saw **@johnataylor**'s comment saying

> The pattern we follow is to defer the creation of the accessor until we need it - this seems to hide the inherent noise the most effectively.

When should I create the accessors if I want to get the `ShoppingCart` (which is inside the `UserProfile` property that I need to access) inside my Dialogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Fast Answer:*
**You should create the accessor in the all the dialogs where you need to manipulate the state.**

*Detailed Answer:*

**CreateProperty** does not physically create the property, it just:

> Creates a property definition and register it with this BotState

**CreateProperty()** will return you a **BotStatePropertyAccessor** from which you can call **GetAsync**,**SetAsync** and **DeleteAsync** those will Get, Set and delete a property from the state cache in the turn context.(Internal cached bot state)

When you call **BotState.SaveChangesAsync()** this will:

> If it has changed, writes to storage the state object that is cached in the current context object for this turn.

Each call of **GetAsync**,**SetAsync** will actually call **BotState.LoadAsync()** first to:

> Reads in  the current state object and caches it in the context
>   object for this turn.

And when **GetAsync()** is called and **no key is found**, it will automatically call **SetAsync** to set that new property

If you are using **AutoSaveStateMiddleware** that middleware will:

> automatically call .SaveChanges() at the end of the turn for all
>   BotState class it is managing.

Comment: That's the answer I've been looking for ages, now I understand. So just to clarify, i should `CreateProperty` in every dialog that needs it in order to get the accessor. And doesn't matter if I call it every turn because the property won't be affected unless i `SetAsync` right?
One last thing, should I initialize the accessors in the Dialog constructor using `CreateProperty` or do I store it in a local variable just when I need it?

Comment: Yes you need to `CreateProperty` in every dialog you need so you can get the accessor, it doesn't matter if you call it every turn since a storage write will only occur when there is actually a change. What i do is inject the UserState in the constructor and initialize the accessor from the constructor into a private field `private IStatePropertyAccessor<UserProfile > _stateAccessor;`. This way if you have a waterfall dialog for example, you can use that same accessor in every step

Comment: I have the UserState in the Startup as singleton. I can DI it to the MainDialog, but then it will have to be passed as parameter to the child dialogs right? Since you have to call the constructor when you `AddDialog(new ShoppingDialog(...))` in the `MainDialog`.

Comment: If you add your dialogs in Startup as transient for ex:             `services.AddTransient<ShoppingDialog>();` In your MainDialog you will only have to AddDialog(shoppingDialog); where shoppingDialog is passed to your main constructor as a parameter, and then in your ShoppingDialog, inject the UserState

Comment: One last question, why should I add the User and Conversation states as transient? Shouldn't adding them as `Singleton` be more accurate for what we want to do? What benefits are there with adding the states as `Transient`?

Comment: @MarcAsmar Is there a way to have the Func pointer in GetAsync be async? In my case, I'm making a network call to generate what the bot is going to say.