# When should I use IStatePropertyAccessor.SetAsync?

Tags: c#, caching, reference, botframework, state

I see some example code use IStatePropertyAccessor.SetAsync method and some does not and only rely on BotState.SaveChangesAsync that normally happen in another method (OnTurnAsync)

Is there any difference between the two and when would I want to use SetAsync?

Comment: Check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58342265/9888221 maybe it can help

Comment: I see, so SetAsync does not actually save the changes but only Set it internally in cache, meaning if I call SetAsync and do not call SaveChangesAsync it won't be saved. Are these operations thread-safe? I plan to have concurrent threads Setting and probably Saving the values of the same property.

Comment: Also I see that StateManagementBot example does not use SetAsync, but changes are still being picked up by SaveChangesAsync. So it looks like SetAsync call is optional, bringing us back to my original question: when would I want to use SetAsync? Is this kind of force-setting a value?

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/939#issuecomment-471617015 i think it will answer your question

Comment: @zape - is my answer acceptable?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes. Marc's link explains the same. The only question left is about thread safety. Is it ok to use the same PropertyAccessor instance in multiple threads?

Comment: @zape - Please accept my answer if it's acceptable. About thread safety, remember that your bot is a web app that will be processing multiple HTTP requests simultaneously on separate threads. The samples I've seen have used BotState instances as singletons, which means they'd be shared between threads. Since BotStatePropertyAccessor mostly just calls the BotState methods I presume BotStatePropertyAccessor instances can also be shared between threads. However, it's rare to share one turn context between concurrent worker threads so it's hard to say if that sort of thing would cause problems.

Comment: Accepted. New user here, took a while to find the accept button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it in terms of reference types and value types. In C#, you can modify an instance of a reference type and those changes will be reflected when accessing the object through any other variable that references that object.

```
var a = new MyClass();
var b = a;
b.Foo = "Some value";
// a = b; // <- You don't need this
Console.WriteLine(a.Foo); // Some value
```

Likewise, when you modify an object you retrieved from a state property accessor, any changes you make will also be made to the object in the cache because it's the same object.

```
var a = await MyStatePropertyAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext);
a.Foo = "Some value";
// await MyStatePropertyAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, a); // <- You don't need this
var b = await MyStatePropertyAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext); // This will be the same as a
turnContext.SendActivityAsync(b.Foo); // Some value
```

However, if for any reason you want to change the object in the cache so that it's now a different object, then you will need `SetAsync`. Maybe you've constructed a new instance of an object or maybe you want to assign a null reference or maybe you're using a type that's copied by value. With normal variable assignments it might look like this:

```
var a = new MyStruct();
var b = a;
b.Foo = "Some value";
a = b; // <- You need this because structs are copied by value
Console.WriteLine(a.Foo); // Some value
```

I want to note that it's good practice to make structs immutable, but I'm altering the struct here just to demonstrate the point of needing to assign it back to `a`. Likewise, when you want to change a state property to a whole new object, you'll need `SetAsync`.

```
var a = await MyStatePropertyAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => null);
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync((a is null).ToString()); // True
await MyStatePropertyAccessor.SetAsync(turnContext, new MyClass());
var b = await MyStatePropertyAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, () => null);
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync((b is null).ToString()); // False
```