# Propagate states to dialogs in MS BotFramework

Tags: botframework

In Microsoft **BotFramework v4** you normally propagate the states (**UserState**, **ConversationState**, **PrivateConversationState**) to a dialog by passing them as parameters to its constructor.

This way:

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        IStorage storage = new MemoryStorage(); // For testing only !
        services.AddSingleton(new UserState(storage));
        services.AddSingleton(new ConversationState(storage));
        // ...
        services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<GoviiBaseDialog>(x => new RootDialog(
            x.GetRequiredService<UserState>(),
            x.GetRequiredService<ConversationState>()
        );
        services.AddTransient<IBot, Bot<RootDialog>>();
    }
}
```

**Bot.cs**

```cs
public class Bot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Dialog
{
    T _dialog;
    BotState _userState, _conversationState;

    public Bot(T dialog, UserState userState, ConversationState conversationState,)
    {
        _userState = userState;
        _conversationState = conversationState;
        _dialog = dialog;
    }

    public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await base.OnTurnAsync(context, cancellationToken);
        await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(context);
        await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(context);
    }

    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _dialog.RunAsync(context, _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**RootDialog.cs**

```cs
public class RootDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    UserState _userState;
    ConversationState _conversationState;

    public RootDialog(UserState uState, ConversationState cState) : base("id")
    {
        _userState = uState;
        _conversationState = cState;

        // Add some dialogs and pass states as parameters
        AddDialog(new CustomDialog_1(uState, cState));
        AddDialog(new CustomDialog_2(uState, cState));
        // ...
        AddDialog(new CustomDialog_N(uState, cState));
    }
}
```

Now let's assume that those **CustomDialogs** again uses some other **CustomDialogs** which needs to access the state. The states have to be passed again and again as parameters to the constructors.

The question is: Is there *another* way to access the states to avoid passing them again and again as parameters?

Comment: This might be an XY problem, so could you explain why you want to pass bot state to your dialogs to begin with? I would think it makes sense to pass specific bot state accessors to dialogs instead of the bot state itself, but I know that wouldn't change the nature of your question.

Comment: I think the reason for passing the BotState instead of accessors is because I'm still new to BF v4 and not very familliar with it. I will refactor my code and update the question in the next days. But yes, this doesn't change the nature of my question.

Comment: I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58338918/how-to-use-state-accessors-to-get-properties-in-bot-framework) saying that passing the state is ok. So is there a drawback to pass the whole state instead of the accessor?

Comment: There are no objective drawbacks, only potential subjective ones depending on how you like to design your bot. But that's not important. I still need to know what you want to use the state to keep track of once it's in the dialogs.

Comment: I use the state to keep track of the recognized entities and the location the user has entered, amongst other things. I need to save those things somewhere for later processing.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy. Yes your answer is acceptable. Thanks for that. `UseBotState` along with getting state from `TurnContext` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you access state in a dialog will depend on the scope of the state.

If the state is scoped to the dialog then you should be using dialog state. More specifically, you should be using the state property of the dialog's associated dialog instance. There's some discussion of that in a recent answer here: [Dialogs keep their variable values in new conversation in MS BotFramework v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801536/dialogs-keep-their-variable-values-in-new-conversation-in-ms-botframework-v4/64813683#64813683)

> (Read about dialog instances [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#dialog-state)). Anything you want your dialog to keep track of, you should put in the associated dialog instance's state object, and the best place to see examples of how to do that is in the SDK source code itself. For example, you can see how a [waterfall dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/WaterfallDialog.cs) keeps track of things like its custom values and what step it's on:
>
> > ```cs
> > // Update persisted step index
> > var state = dc.ActiveDialog.State;
> > state[StepIndex] = index;
> > ```

If the state has a greater scope than one instance of one dialog, you can pass the bot state objects to your dialogs like you've been doing. This can potentially be made easier if you put the dialogs in dependency injection so that your bot state can be automatically injected into their constructors. If your dialogs access state properties that are also used outside of the dialogs then it makes sense to give the dialogs a state property accessor instead of the state itself, reducing redundancy and separating concerns.

If you want to make sure your bot state is accessible anywhere you have a turn context, there's actually a built-in way to automatically add your bot state to turn state every turn. This is with the [`UseBotState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.adapterextensions.usebotstate) extension method:

```cs
adapter.UseBotState(userState, conversationState);
```

You can then retrieve the state like this:

```cs
var userState = turnContext.TurnState.Get<UserState>();
var conversationState = turnContext.TurnState.Get<ConversationState>();
```