# Dialogs keep their variable values in new conversation in MS BotFramework v4

Tags: c#, azure-storage, chatbot, botframework

I'm using MS BotFramework v4. There is a `RootDialog` which starts `Dialog_A` or `Dialog_B` depending on what the user input is.

## TL;DR

If a new conversation is started after a conversation and the bot isn't restarted, private variables of dialogs to which a value (which is not the initial value) has already be assigned, are not reseted to their initial value leading to unexpected behavior. How can this be avoided?

## Detailed

Let's assume the following scenario:
Each of these dialogs has some private variables to control whether to output a long or a short introduction message. The long one should only be be outputted on the first time this dialog is started. If the conversation again reaches the dialog only the short message should be printed.

Implementation looks like this:

**RootDialog.cs**

```cs
public class RootDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    private bool isLongWelcomeText = true;
    // Some more private variables follow here

    public RootDialog() : base("rootId") {
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[] {
            WelcomeStep,
            DoSomethingStep,
            FinalStep
        });
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnContext> WelcomeStep(WaterfallStepContext ctx, CancellationToken token) {
        if(isLongWelcomeText) {
            await ctx.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("A welcome message and some detailed bla bla about the bot"));
            isLongWelcomeText = false;
        } else {
            await ctx.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("A short message that hte bot is waiting for input"));
        }
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnContext> DoSomethingStep(WaterfallStepContext ctx, CancellationToken token) {
        // call Dialog_A or Dialog_B depending on the users input
        // Dialog X starts
        await ctx.BeginDialogAsync("Dialog_X", null, token);
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnContext> FinalStep(WaterfallStepContext ctx, CancellationToken token) {
        // After dialog X has ended, RootDialog continues here and simply ends
        await ctx.EndDialogAsync(null, token);
    }
}
```

`Dialog_A` and `Dialog_B` are structured the same way.

## The problem

If the bot handles its first conversation, everything works as expected (the long welcome text is printed to the user and `isLongWelcomeText` is set to `false` in `WelcomeStep`. When I then start a new conversation (new conversationId and userId) `isLongWelcomeText` still is set to `false` which leads to the bot outputting the short welcome text in a new conversation to a new user.

In BotFramework v3 dialogs were serialized and deserialized together with all variable values.

If I'm right in BF v4 dialogs aren't serialized anymore.

## The question

How can this be fixed? Is there a better way to do this?

## Remarks

I'm using `UserState` and `ConversationState` which are serialized and reset on new conversations. But I don't want to store every private variable value of each dialog in the states. This cannot be the way to go.

Thanks in advace

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should think of it as a mistake to put instance member variables in a dialog class. There may be some cases when it could work, but those cases will not involve trying to persist some kind of state between turns. There are three main problems with using any kind of in-memory variables of your bot classes to persist state between turns:

1. **It won't be scoped correctly.** This is the problem you noticed already. You've clearly defined your `isLongWelcomeText` as something that should be specific to a user and/or a conversation, but because it's in your bot's own memory that's used to process every conversation for every user then it won't be able to distinguish between different conversations and users.
2. **It won't scale correctly.** This means that even if your bot is just talking to one user in one conversation, if the bot is deployed in some hosting service like Azure that scales sideways then multiple instances of your bot may be running. Different instances of your bot will have different memory, so if you want to design a bot correctly then you need to act as though every turn will be processed by a totally different instance of the bot, maybe on a totally different server. One instance can't access the memory of another instance.
3. **It will be lost when the app restarts.** Even if you only have one user, one conversation, *and* one bot instance, you still want to be able to stop your bot and then start it again without ruining the conversation. If you're using the bot's memory then you can't do that.

The second two problems even apply when you're using `MemoryStorage` and not just when you're using in-memory variables. You may have guessed that the solution is to use bot state (and to connect the bot state to some storage class other than `MemoryStorage` when the bot is deployed).

You are correct that in v3 entire instance objects of dialog classes would get serialized into persistent state. That came with its own set of problems and didn't always make logical sense, so in v4 the things that gets serialized are [`DialogInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.dialoginstance) objects. (Read about dialog instances [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#dialog-state)). Anything you want your dialog to keep track of, you should put in the associated dialog instance's state object, and the best place to see examples of how to do that is in the SDK source code itself. For example, you can see how a [waterfall dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/WaterfallDialog.cs) keeps track of things like its custom values and what step it's on:

> ```cs
> // Update persisted step index
> var state = dc.ActiveDialog.State;
> state[StepIndex] = index;
> ```

Comment: That means that I simply have to save those instance member values in the ActiveDialog.State? What would be the best place to save the values in the state? I suspect that saving has to be done in each WaterfallStep before the step ends? And loading from state in the ComponentDialogs ResumeDialogAsync maybe?

Comment: Waterfall dialogs provide a "values" property in their waterfall step contexts so you don't have to worry about accessing the dialog state explicitly. I'm now realizing that I should have mentioned that a dialog instance's state might not work in your case, because you want your `isLongWelcomeText` to be scoped to the conversation and not to the dialog. This means serializing the dialog like in v3 would not have worked either, because a new instance of the dialog class would be constructed every time it gets added onto the stack. However, you might be fine if it's a persistent root dialog.

Comment: Hm, ok, now I'm confused. Using instance members is wrong when they are scoped to a single conversation. Using the dialog instance state does not work. Where should I then store these values (regardless of what values this could be)? In the ConversationState? For each single Dialog?? You can't be serious!

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, `isLongWelcomeText` keeps track of whether a welcome message has already been sent to the user or not. You shouldn't need any kind of state for that, because a welcome message should be sent in response to a one-time event, namely a conversation update. However, if you do want to keep track of it then it seems like that information would be scoped to the conversation or the user and not to the dialog, which means you should use conversation state or user state that's separate from dialog state and not in a dialog instance.